# Parsing strings with JS friendly regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

I'm trying to use regex that has to be JS friendly to parse parts of a string. I'm building a scraper using the [webscraper.io](http://webscraper.io/) extension for Chrome. But I'm having trouble. I need a min and max lifespan but they are in one string "Life Span: 10 to 12 years"

How can I use regex to return "10" for the min and another to return "12" for the max? Needs to be as simple as possible. Ideally I need to run a separate selector for each. So it would be two different regex. I can grab the 10 with \d+ but I don't know how to isolate the last digits in the string. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To get all the numbers from a `String`, you can use `\d+`. Hence you can add the results to an array with a `while` loop, and get the Min/Max value from them:

**Example 1** - Using functions

```
var min;
var max;
var text = "Being under 18 may require parental signature. "
         + "You must be at least 16 years in older to apply";

function getMinAndMax(string){
    var p = RegExp("\\d+", "g"),

    match, results = [];

    while (match = p.exec(string))
        results.push(match[0]); // [18, 16]

    return [Math.min.apply(null, results), // 16
    Math.max.apply(null, results)];        // 18
}

var ages = getMinAndMax(text); // [16, 18]
console.log("Min: " + ages[0]);
console.log("Max: " + ages[1]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oro4djpq/

**Example 2** - Direct

```
var p = RegExp("\\d+", "g"),
text = "Life Span: 10 to 12 years",
match, results = [];

while (match = p.exec(text))
    results.push(match[0]); // [10, 12]

console.log("Min: " + Math.min.apply(null, results)); // [10]
console.log("Max: " + Math.max.apply(null, results)); // [12]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rzo31teb/